# ¿Cómo puedo restringir el acceso a un usuario en laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

Un cordial saludo a la comunidad, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema basado en laravel 5.8, y no consigo como resolver lo siguiente: como puedo bloquear o desbloquear el acceso a un usuario al ingresar sesión.

Actualmente tengo en la base de datos, la tabla users, el campo user_status y el modelo creado en el laravel.

Instale el sistema de autenticación de laravel por defecto, y  maquete la vista con mi plantilla.

Solo me valida usuario y clave, pero como hago para que el momento de este proceso también me valide **user_status** en la bd.

este es mi código fuente del controlador **LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
 use AuthenticatesUsers;
 protected $redirectTo = '/';


 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

 }    
}
```

Agradecido de antemano si alguien me puede ayudar con el problema.

Tengo además este código fuente pero no se como verificar si se realiza adecuadamente y lo encontré implementado en el LoginController de otro proyecto.

No se que recibe como $request

Como le paso la variable $user_active, que puede ser un 0 o un 1 desde la bd.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user_active)
{       
    if ($user_active==0) {
      $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['error' => 'Este usuario no  esta activo en el sistema']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Carlos. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor edita tu pregunta y muestranos el código que tienes, así podemos ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Crea una instancia del usuario, lee el campo user_active, y si es igual a lo que quieres, haces redirect, sino, que continue

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto al comentario: "Crea una instancia del usuario, lee el campo user_active, y si es igual a lo que quieres, haces redirect, sino, que continue."

Entendi que user ya estaba instanciado pero en otra clase que se llama AuthenticatesUsers de Illuminate\Foundation\Auth y no en LoginController

Utilice el método y le pase la tabla usuarios de mi bd

```
  protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {   

    if ($user->user_status==0) {            
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();            
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['error' => 'Este usuario no está activo en el sistema']);        
    }
    else
    {

        //Aqui se establecen las variables de sesion del usuario
        session(['id_user' => auth()->user()->id]);       
        session(['business_name' => auth()->user()->first_name]);
        session(['identification_code' => auth()->user()->identification_code]);
        session(['username' => auth()->user()->username]);
        session(['email' => auth()->user()->email]);

    }

}
```